# Creating JSON file and saving to it

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am really new to JSON and am trying my best so please excuse me for any obvious mistakes I have made.

I am trying to turn an object into a JSON string ready to be saved and sent into a JSON file.

This is what I have so far, what would the next step be?

Thank you in advance!

```
function saveCard(username) {
    var BingoData = {"username": username, "cardnumber": serial, "cells": []};
    for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        BingoData.Cells.push(tablecells[i].innerHTML);
    }

    var BingoCards = JSON.stringify(BingoData);

}
```

Comment: Save where? On a local server, local file, web server ..?

Comment: Yeah just create a local JSON file that the data will be saved to and read from!

Comment: That's something JS can't do.

Comment: you'll need a backend write the data

Comment: @Teemu what is required to write to a .json file?

Comment: in the browser or node?

Comment: @EGxo A server, maybe nodejs, so you can do it with JS.

Comment: browser @DanielA.White